# CRM 2011 Performing FetchXML group by on custom option set value

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I want to be able to perform a FetchXML request that sums a value while grouping on a field that is a custom option set but I don't get the expected results.

All that is returned is the summed up values, not the related custom option set value that it relates to so I have no idea what the returned values relate to.

This is the fetchXML request which appears to be correct:

```xml
<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
    <entity name='opportunity'> 
          <attribute name='estimatedvalue' alias='opportunity_sum' aggregate='sum' /> 
          <attribute name='koo_opportunitytype' alias='koo_opportunitytype' groupby='true' /> 
    </entity> 
</fetch>
```

Each value that is returned only has 1 attribute...the *opportunity_sum* value.

If I group by say, customer id, then the returned values are summed up correctly and a reference is returned to the related customer for each summed value which is what I would expect.

Is it not possible to group by a custom option set value? This seems to work fine with standard system option set values such as status code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have verified that your fetch xml works just fine as long as the data is clean.  If all of your `koo_opportunitytype` values for opportunities are null, it will not return an attribute for them.  I'm assuming that you're only getting one entity returned?  Also if any estimated value is null for a group, the sum will not be returned either.  This means you'll probably want to add a filter to exclude null values from your sum.